# Select HTML element with javascript based on attribute

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Although i've become quite well versed in jQuery unfortunately my Javascript is somewhat lacking and I don't have access to jQuery in this instance, so please no "use jQuery" answers.

Basically Google Analytics enables me to track social clicks as so:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'like', 'http://domain.com/somepage']);
```

Now I have various links on my page like so:

```
<a href="#myfacebook#" track_social="facebook"><img src="facebook_button" /></a>
<a href="#mytwitter#" track_social="twitter"><img src="twitter_button" /></a>
<a href="#mygoogleplus#" track_social="googleplus"><img src="googleplus_button" /></a>
<a href="#mypinterest#" track_social="pinterest"><img src="pinterest_button" /></a>
```

Now what I would like is to track clicks on each of these and run the Google Analytics code demonstrated above. If I was using jQuery I would do something like this:

```
$('a[track_social]').click(function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', $(this).attr('track_social'), 'click', $(this).attr('href')]);  
});
```

But as I said I don't have access to jQuery so how would I do this using general Javascript?

It doesn't necessarily have to use the "track_social" attribute, I could put something else in, but it can't be unique ID's for every single one as they'll be appearing in multiple ways throughout the site and multiple times on various pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That jQuery can be ported directly to native DOM APIs:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('a[track_social]')
).forEach(function(i) {
    i.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        _gaq.push(['_trackSocial',
            e.target.getAttribute('track_social'),
            'click', e.target.href]);  
    }, false);
});
```

Please note that while this code is fully standards-compliant, it requires JavaScript 1.6 for `forEach` (supported in most major browsers, but only in IE 9+), and it requires `addEventListener` and `querySelectorAll` (supported in most major browsers, but only in IE 8+). You could add to this solution if you wanted wider browser support.

---

Supplementary code #1:

```
var n = document.querySelectorAll('a[track_social]');
for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++)
    n[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        _gaq.push(['_trackSocial',
            e.target.getAttribute('track_social'),
            'click', e.target.href]);  
    }, false);
```

Comment: Doesn't work in all browsers though... you should at least mention explicitly where it works and where it does not work.

Comment: You forgot to change $(this).attr('href') to e.target.getAttribute('href');

Comment: Felix, nothing works in 'all browsers', so it's really a subjective question of how far back you are willing to go. I'll update my answer with information on where it works, though. BenniKa, thanks; I've just fixed that now.

Comment: +1 For first time seeing querySelectAll. I had implement a function like this in my javascript framework, because I didn't know, that it existed allreay.

Comment: Cheers for the answer how does this work? Do I need to fill "array" with something in the first place? A quick test gives me the following error: "Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a[track_social]")).addEventListener is not a function"

Comment: No, you don't need to replace anything. What browser and version are you using?

Comment: I think you updated your answer from what I tried first, what is there now works on Firefox 11.

Comment: What alternatives are there to forEach to get it to work on IE8?

Comment: To your first comment: I remember now; I added in the `forEach` later because my initial answer meant you'd be trying to bind an event to an array, which obviously wouldn't work. To your second comment: please see *supplementary code #1*. It is an alternative that doesn't require `forEach`, and should work on IE8 (but still not IE7 or below).

Comment: Thanks but the supplementary code doesn't seem to work in IE9 Compatibility mode, which I think should be roughly equivalent to IE8. Works in all other browsers though as does the original code.

Comment: I thought the compatibility mode was to emulate IE7.

Comment: Hmm perhaps you are right I can't find a clear answer on how to test this in IE8. I'll accept your answer anyway its been very helpful and thorough!

Comment: Thanks; I'm happy to help however I can.

Answer (score 0):

you have options:

you could go for the [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) which acts like CSS (and jQuery selectors). it gives you a `NodeList` which is an array-like collection of the elements retrieived.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[track_social]');
//gives us [element,element,element...], loop and attach

for(var i; i<links.length;i++){
    links[i].addEventListener(...);
}
```

another way is to get all `<a>` tags and test them for your attribute

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i; i<links.length;i++){
    if(links[i][yourAttribute]){
        links[i].addEventListener(...);
    }
}
```

but there are a few caveats. `querySelectorAll()` is [not supported by some browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=querysele) (screw IE). also, IE has it's version of [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) which is [`attachEvent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Please note that both qSA and aEL are supported by IE8 and above.

Comment: yup, i have a link in my post for that.